# How to send json data in request body through GET request to external API in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I must send json data to external api for post method to take data from this external api.
json data i want to send is like that.
{
"key1" : "value1",
"key2" : "value2",
"key3" : "value3"
}
How to send json data in request body through GET request to external API in Spring Boot application

Comment: are you still looking at this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the JSON data is large or contains special characters, it may not be practical to encode the entire JSON data in the URL. It is better to utilise a POST request instead of a GET request to transmit the JSON data within the request body. If there is a need to do it, you can try this:

```
public void sendData(String jsonData) throws URISyntaxException {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    String url = "https://yoururl.com/api?data=" + jsonData;
    RequestEntity<?> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(headers, HttpMethod.GET, new URI(url));

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class); // GET request
    String responseBody = responseEntity.getBody();

    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I need to use my spring boot application to make a request to an external application in order to receive data from it, but in order to receive this data I need to send data in json format from my application. the method used by the external api post , my method is get , but it does not matter which method to use in my application. How can i do this?

Comment: This is not recommended as it was mentioned in another answer here. The code I posted can work, however, it's not recommended per the HTTP protocol standards. Ideally, if the external API expects JSON data, you should use a POST request instead of a GET request to send the data in the request body.

Comment: i understood. But how i can do this with method post. Can u show example?